# Condicion para productos no encontrados por medio de un filter range - React.js

Tags: reactjs

Hola estoy la siguiente [app](https://husdady.github.io/simulador-de-compras/) y tengo problemas para crear una condicional que me retorne false cada vez no encuentre productos entre los precios establecidos por los inputs range, esta funcion me retorna un mensaje de que no se ha encontrado ningun producto con ese precio:

```js
notFound = ()=>{
    const minValue = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]')[0].value,
    maxValue = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]')[1].value;
    let filter;
    celulares.filter(item=> {

      if ( (Number(item.precio) >= Number(maxValue)|| Number(item.precio) <= Number(minValue)) || (Number(item.precio) >= Number(minValue) || Number(item.precio) <= Number(maxValue)) ){
        filter = true;
      } else {
        filter = false;
      }
    });
    return filter;
  }
```

Bueno como ya escribi arriba, necesito retornar un mensaje de no se ha encontrado cada vez que no encuentre coincidencias con algun precio de algun producto. Aca pueden ver los componentes de la [app](https://github.com/Husdady/simulador-de-compras/tree/main/components). Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un **[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)** podría servir si estas buscando valores según condiciones.

```js
const prices = [395, 504, 99, 105, 756, 452];
const min = 100;
const max = 500;

const findRange = () => {
  const aux = prices.filter((x) => x >= min && x <= max);
  console.log(aux);
  //return aux || [];
};
findRange();
```

De todas maneras te adjunto un **[ejemplo](https://codesandbox.io/s/filtro-condicional-otw8s)** en `React` para que lo revises y nos comentes como te va!

Comment: Lo probare mas tarde, ahorita no estoy en mi laptop

Comment: estuve probando y no funciona como yo quiero, estoy intentandolo de otra manera, ps debe funcionar algo asi: debe retornar los productos de los cuales sus precios que esten entre los valores de los inputs number, y cuando no encuentre coincidencia debe retornar un mensaje de no encontrado, algo asi como se muestra cuando todos los checkboxes no estan activados.

Comment: Esta raro...cómo estás enviando ese mínimo y máximo hacia tu función? Puede ser que el formato y/o tipo sea distinto del que estás comparando

Comment: Hice una simulación de lo que estoy tratando de lograr en este enlace: https://codepen.io/Husdady/pen/rNWBeBv, te explico, siempre que la variable filter retorne true, react me va a renderizar productos y cuando sea otro valor que no sea true, vuelve a renderizar todo el contenido para retornar un h2 con un mensaje de no se ha encontrado nada

Comment: Por eso mismo, tengo que retornar false, siempre y cuando no encuentre precios entre las dos cantidades de los inputs number

Comment: @Husdady clone tu repo y estuve analizando tu código. El filter que recorre los celulares está un poco extraño ya que no necesitas realizar un `if` dentro de el. Además sólo te serviría guardar el resultado de ese `Array.filter` en una variable y crear la condición según esa variable.

De todas maneras edite la respuesta y te adjunte un codesandbox basado en React para que lo revises. Si bien está orientado a componentes funcionales no te costará entenderlo, ya que posees experiencia en React. 

Cualquier cosa que no entiendas me avisas :)

Comment: Ok muchas gracias Paulo, estudiare tu codigo, si tengo algo de experiencia en React, hace unas semanas estuve aprendiendo React, y acerca de filter, estuve viendo mas acerca de este metodo y no necesitas hacer 'condicionales' ya que siempre retornara;  lo que retorne la condicion

Comment: Paulo pude resolver lo que no podia hacer gracias a tu ayuda! . La lógica estaba en verificar el número de productos renderizados en el DOM, tu lógica me ayudo a entender mejor lo que estaba haciendo! . Además pude optimizar el código

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con lo que comentas te sugiero cambiar la condición de OR por AND y dentro de este verificar que item.precio sea >= (mayor igual) a minValue Y que item.precio sea <= (menor igual) a maxValue.

```
if ( item.precio >= minValue && item.precio <= maxValue )       {
    filter = true;
  } else {
    filter = false;
  }
```

De esta manera por ejemplo si el precio es de 5 no pasara la evaluación de minValue = 10 o si el precio es de 30 no pasará la evaluación de maxValue = 20.

Comment: ya probe con ese metodo y no retorna false por alguna razon, sigue retornando true, lo he comprobado desde react developers